# C# compiler including local path in EXE

Tags: c#, .net

When I compile a Release project (DEBUG is not enabled) in VS 2010, I'm seeing things like this in the generated EXE:

C:\Code\Test\Test\obj\x86\Release\Test.pdb

Why is this, and how can I disable it?  I've tried Googling, but can't find much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allthough i havent actually tried looking in the exe file, you can disable generation of pdb files (and presumably their inclusion in the exe) from the project properties under Build > Advanced > Debug info. if you set this value to 'None', nothing should be generated

Even for release the default is to generate pdb files only.

Comment: Yup this works, just confirmed. My full name is in my path at work and it always bothered me that this info was compiled INTO the exe. Glad to know how to fix that now.

Comment: Thanks, that works here too.  Before I close this question (and accept aL3891's answer), could I just check whether it's a good idea to change this setting?  I presume this PDB file isn't used at all in the Release EXE, but then I wonder why this setting is enabled by default at all.

Comment: Sure, they arent really needed for release builds anyway, they might be useful if you get an exception and want to debug though, but they are not necceary :)

Answer (score 0):

These files are for debugging. They contain (among other thins) information on matching breakpoint in code to place in the compiled code. They should not be shipped with the binaries.

Comment: I don't think that's what he's talking about. He means that if you view your exe in Notepad you can see potentially private information like path names etc.